# How to handle blob security user specific

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an document management application where user upload the document and it get saved in azure blob. I want to know how to manage blob access user specific. Suppoese user A create a document and upload to azure blob, user B should not be able to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Makogon  pointed my message probably was not clear. So let me rewrite it

To solve your problem you will need combination of azure and your application. 
The way to solve it would be.

1. When user uploads file create Blob container with **private access** and name it for instance as user id.
2. Then to upload actual file you can handle it in 2 ways first way is to upload directly via your app, second way you can use [SAS tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegating-access-with-a-shared-access-signature) (So you will get url with write permissions and ANYBODY who has this link can write to that folder, this is why I would recommend to limit it by time and IP, SAS provide that possibility), then your backed will return generated url with token where client can upload file (directly from users machine)
3. Same way if user wants to download files then you will need to send request to your application to get download link (Where using SAS you can create a token so user can get access to his container, it also prevent user to modify url, since if they do they will get rejected since token is created for that specific file).

Azure has [RBAC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/) but then you can grant read all, write all which is not you are looking for.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: Azure certainly provides a way to lock down storage. You even mention SAS (and there are shared access *policies* as well). How is it that Azure doesn't handle this? Create all containers and images as private, and then nobody has access. True, things don't magically happen, but blob- (or container-) level security is built directly into Azure Storage.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for pointing out I think now message should be correct.